# Hibernate Criteria using FIND_IN_SET

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a below requirement in my project:
  (1) Request object to an API which is off list type (of strings).
  (2) We are using Hibernate Criteria to fetch the resultSet from the mysql database.
  (3) One of the columns is having Pipe delimited values.
  (4) We have to fetch the rows against **each** of the request object's values.

```
Table: user_info  
-----------------------------------------------------------
 user_id       user_name    .. .. .. ..   hobbies
-----------------------------------------------------------
 101           johnSmith    .. .. .. ..   Traveling|Painting|Gardening
 102           tomWatch     .. .. .. ..   Gardening|Reading|Fishing
 103           robertPatt   .. .. .. ..   Dancing|Gardening|Swimming|Blogging
 104           julieAdams   .. .. .. ..   Bicycling|Fishing|Socializing

 JSON Request object:
 {
   searchParams : {
       hobbies : [ 
         "Gardening",
         "Fishing",
         "Reading"
       ],
     ..
     ..
     ..
   }
  }


  Java Code 


  if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(searchParams.getHobbies())) {
        List<String> reqHobbies = searchParameters.getHobbies();
        Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
        for(String hobby : reqHobbies) {
            Criterion criterion = Restrictions.like("hobbies", "|" + hobby + "|");
            disjunction.add(criterion);
        }
        criteria.add(disjunction);
    }
```

This query will not work as the starting of the value (from table) is not having "|" symbol..

If I modify the critieria API to generate the query in the following fashion,

```
select * from user_info
where hobbies like '%Gardening|%' or hobbies like '%Fishing|%' or hobbies like '%Reading|%' 
 or hobbies like '%|Gardening|%' or hobbies like '%|Fishing|%' or hobbies like '%|Reading|%' 
 or hobbies like '%|Gardening%' or hobbies like '%|Fishing%' or hobbies like '%|Reading%';
```

This design also has a flaw. The only way to solve this by using FIND_IN_SET.

Mysql query:

```
select * from user_info 
where hobbies find_in_set('Gardening', replace(hobbies, '|', ',')) 
or hobbies find_in_set('Fishing', replace(hobbies, '|', ','))
or hobbies find_in_set('Reading', replace(hobbies, '|', ','));
```

How to create a find_in_set query using Hibernate Criteria? Using @Formula ?

Comment: You need another table where you can store multiple rows for each user, with one hobby per row. This is the way to store a many-to-many relationship in a relational database. Then you don't need to use FIND_IN_SET() or worry about which character separates hobbies.

Comment: Thank you Bill for the answer. Since having multiple tables is not an option, we are stuck with this. Not sure how to solve on this.

Comment: @SrinivasLakshman any new on this?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is building [query dynamically](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA/wiki/Dynamic-Queries) and not using Criteria API, you may build it with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA), like in this:

```java
public List<UserInfo> filterByHobbies(List<String> hobbies) {

    Function1<UserInfo, Boolean> dynamicFilter = buildOr(hobbies);

    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((UserInfo user) -> {
        SELECT(user);
        FROM(user);

        WHERE(dynamicFilter.apply(hobbies);
    });

    return query.createQuery(getEntityManager(), UserInfo.class).getResultList();
}

private Function1<UserInfo, Boolean> buildOr(List<String> hobbies) {
    Function1<UserInfo, Boolean> criteria = Function1.FALSE();

    for (String hobby : hobbies)
        criteria = criteria.or(u -> FIND_IN_SET(parameter(hobby),
                                                u.getHobbies().replace('|', ',')) > 0);

    return criteria;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Konstantin. Unfortunately, we are still using Java-7 and not using FluentJPA. (Just regular Hibernate). Kindly let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: In this case Criteria API is probably the way to go

Answer (score 0):

This is an option in some cases:

```
xxxRepository.findAll((root, query, cb) -> {

   List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(param)) {
        Expression<Integer> findInSetFun = cb.function("FIND_IN_SET", Integer.class,             
                            cb.literal(param), root.get("targetColName"));

        predicateList .add(cb.greaterThan(findInSetFun, 0));
    }
}, pageable);
```

Comment: I tried this solution but its not forming the order by clause so how to make a query by this in order by clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
Expression<Integer> function = criteriaBuilder.function("find_in_set", Integer.class,
                    criteriaBuilder.literal(warehouseList), root.get("sWarehouseIdList"));
            
Predicate sWarehouseIdList = criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(function, 0);
            predicateList.add(sWarehouseIdList);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Entity> cq = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
    Root<Entity> contentMediaRoot = cq.from(Entity.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            
    predicates.add(cb.gt(cb.function("FIND_IN_SET",
                                        Integer.class,
             criteriaBuilder.function(
            "REPLACE",
            String.class,
            cb.literal(searchDTO.getEnum().name()),
            criteriaBuilder.literal("|"),
            criteriaBuilder.literal(",")),
             contentMediaRoot.get("hobbies")
                 ), 0
              ));
    cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    TypedQuery<Entity> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    List<Entity> contentMediaList = query.getResultList();
```

> The answer has already been provided above, but I believe it may not
> be complete. To provide a more comprehensive solution: I used a
> List mapped to a varchar field in the database as a
> comma-separated string. However, it's advisable not to use this
> approach. Instead, consider saving the enum values in a separate table
> and establishing a mapping relation. This way, you can easily search
> within that mapping.

MySQL FIND_IN_SET() function is a built-in MySQL string function responsible for discovering the position of a given specific string provided in a list of strings separated by a comma
PLEASE NOTE: Please ensure that you adjust the SQL function and syntax to match your database system if you're not using MySQL, as different databases may have different functions for this purpose.

Comment: REPLACE function that allows you to replace occurrences of one substring with another within a string.
**Please adapt the code to your specific use case and database system.**